# Is it possible to write this Rust code into semantically equivalent C++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11, rust, recursive-datastructures

I stumbled upon this [Rust example in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29#Syntax) and I am wondering if its possible to convert it to semantically equivalent C++ code?

The program defines a recursive datastructure and implements methods upon it.  Recursive datastructures require a layer of indirection, which is provided by a unique pointer, constructed via the `box` operator.  *(These are analogous to the C++ library type `std::unique_ptr`, though with more static safety guarantees.)*

```
fn main() {
    let list = box Node(1, box Node(2, box Node(3, box Empty)));
    println!("Sum of all values in the list: {:i}.", list.multiply_by(2).sum());
}

// `enum` defines a tagged union that may be one of several different kinds
// of values at runtime.  The type here will either contain no value, or a
// value and a pointer to another `IntList`.

enum IntList {
    Node(int, Box<IntList>),
    Empty
}

// An `impl` block allows methods to be defined on a type.

impl IntList {
    fn sum(self) -> int {
        match self {
            Node(value, next) => value + next.sum(),
            Empty => 0
        }
    }

    fn multiply_by(self, n: int) -> Box<IntList> {
        match self {
            Node(value, next) => box Node(value * n, next.multiply_by(n)),
            Empty => box Empty
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently in C++ version Rusts `enum` should be replaced with `union`, Rusts `Box` should be replaced with `std::unique_ptr` and Rusts *Node tuple* should be `std::tuple` type but I just cant wrap my head around how to write equivalent implementation in C++.

I know this is probably not practical (and definitely not the correct way to do things in C++) but I just wanted to see how these languages compare (C++11 features flexible enough for this kind of tinkering?). I would also like to compare compiler generated assembly for semantically equivalent implementations (if even possible).

Comment: Do you want to "press" it in a somewhat valid C++ code or do you want a C++-like C++ code doing the same thing? Somehow, you´re talking of both things.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but without pattern matching, it's ugly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e4c80512fa9d739 (There are of course libraries for pattern matching in C++. I replaced it with the "horrible visitor pattern" here.)

Comment: What is C++-like C++ code? By "semantically equivalent" I mean that C++ versios should implement recursive data structure with union which has tuple (integer value and next node) and "Empty" pointer as its members. An of course implement sum() and multiply_by() for the structure. This is just hypothetical example so the C++ version is probably not idiomatic nor practical.

Comment: Of course, you can also write that slightly different in C++ to avoid that pattern matching / visitor / union thing altogether: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2985c5a6c47c176f (though this is requiring that `std::pair` works with incomplete types, which is not guaranteed)

Comment: @dyp [res.on.functions]/2? UB?

Comment: `std::cout << "Sum of all values in the list: 12.\n";` is a semantically equivalent C++ program. ;)

Comment: @Columbo Yes, that's what I've meant with "not guaranteed". Though I think you can work around that issue here by defining the dtor yourself and not using `unique_ptr<Node>` but `unique_ptr<Node>&&` as the parameter type (and similar tricks for other special member functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not a C++11 expert.  Consume with a requisite dose of salt.

As others have commented, there's a few ways of interpreting your question.  I'm going to go with an overly aggressive interpretation, since it's the only interesting one:

**No**, it is *not* possible to translate that Rust code into equivalent C++ code.  Can you translate it into a program that provides the same output?  They're both turing complete, so of course you can.  Can you translate it so that *all* semantics in the original are preserved?  No.

Most of it *can* be translated such that it preserves the actual behaviour.  Rust-style `enum`s can be replaced by `struct`s with both a tag field and a `union`, along with writing appropriate operator overloads to ensure that you correctly destroy the members of *only* the variant that's actually stored.  You can (presumably) use `unique_ptr` in such a way that the memory gets allocated *first* and then the new value is written directly into the allocation, so there's no copy.  I believe you can rewrite `fn sum(self)` so that it uses an rvalue `this` (although I've never done this, so I could easily be wrong).

But the one thing you *cannot* do in C++, to my knowledge, is replicate linear types.  There is no way to statically enforce that a moved value cannot be used again.  The best you can do is runtime checks, which must necessarily involve additional overhead.  This also plays into why you can't have a non-nullable `unique_ptr`: you wouldn't ever be able to move it, since you have to leave the moved variable in a *usable* state.

Now, that having been said, I should disclaim the previous statement by noting that *currently*, the Rust compiler emits some runtime checks for dropped (*i.e.* moved) values, in the form of drop flags.  The plan, last I checked, was to remove these runtime checks in favour of purely static destruction, hopefully before 1.0.

Comment: The current plan isn't quite *purely* static destruction. It is static destruction where possible, falling back to stack drop flags (i.e. still an improvement over what we have now) when there is conditional dropping e.g. `if cond { drop(foo) }` will create a boolean on the stack to control if `foo` needs to be dropped at the end of the outer scope.